# Django: initialize form with few instances of field

Tags: python, django, django-forms, duplicates, fieldset

I have a django `ModelForm` to create/edit some objects.

I have an ability in UI to add new additional fields, like here:
http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/dynamic-form-fields-add-amp-remove-bs3

and I'm gathering data from all the fields(main and additional) and saving into database as a list:

for example:

I have a `name` input field in `ModelForm` and few additional `name` fields added in UI. I'm sending an request like this:

`name=test1&name=test2&name=test3` and so on..and saving in into DB like:

`name = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']`

Here everything is fine, but...

When I want to show my form to edit existing element, I really don't know how to load data from this list `name = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']` into my `ModelForm` + how to generate these additional fields with data..

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 1):

I have not done this yet but the project I am currently working on will require it in the future so I have looked into a few sources.
Although [this tutorial](https://collingrady.wordpress.com/2008/02/18/editing-multiple-objects-in-django-with-newforms/) is pretty old I think it contains some key concepts that still apply.
The tutorial deals with the django tutorial of having a poll with multiple choices. The code below outlines that there should be three choice forms rendered along side one poll question.

```
pform = PollForm(instance=Poll())
cforms = [ChoiceForm(prefix=str(x), instance=Choice()) for x in range(0,3)]
```

You say you want your form to show the existing element for editing. 
**So here Choice() should be replaced with an instance of the model**, so for you you'd do something like instance=name1 where name1 = Name.objects.get(id='1') or some other query to get an instance of the model.

The author of the tutorial also makes a note of this problem:

"And with that, you now have a view which can add a Poll and 3 Choice objects for it at once.

Making a view to edit the same objects is much similar, you just need to query the Poll and Choice objects and use them instead of the empty instances. You can also use the Choice IDs as the prefixes for the ChoiceForm instances. The great thing with using ModelForm is that once you change the instance arg from a new object to an existing one, it becomes an edit form instead of an add form, so you don’t have to change any internals to go from adding to editing."

Comment: I don't think that's good idea, because you'll alway create a duplicated form(with all the data), when I need just only 1 field